# Can we add images with label in react native's actionSheetIOS

Tags: uiactionsheet, react-native-ios, react-native, react-native-image

I want to show images with title in ActionSheet buttons like this:

[image]

Code I am using is

```
var BUTTONS = [
  'Investigated and Resolved',
  'Under Investigation',
  'Action Required',
  'Urgent Action Required',
  // 'Delete',
  'Cancel',
];
var CANCEL_INDEX = 4;

showActionSheet = () => {
    ActionSheet.showActionSheetWithOptions({
        title: 'Flag the status of the event',
        options: BUTTONS,
        cancelButtonIndex: CANCEL_INDEX,
      },
      (buttonIndex) => {
        this.setState({ clicked: BUTTONS[buttonIndex] });
      });
  }
```

Is there a way to style text or add images?

Answer (score 0):

ActionSheetIOS is implementing the native UIAlertController, which does not let you customize your text or add images to the buttons. At least not in a non-hacky way, and you surely won't be able to do that via ActionSheetIOS.

You most likely will have to use a custom JS implementation like react-native-actionsheet.

Comment: Can this be achieved with react-native-actionsheet-native?